# Express.js passing variable in dynamically created route

Tags: javascript, express

I am creating routes in express js from json file with following structure

```
{
  "/home":{
    "token":"ksdjfglkas"
  },
  "/logout":{
    "token":"ksdjfglksaudhf"
  }
}
```

I need to be able to access the token inside the routes function. The js that i am using for generating the route is

```
for(var endpoint in context){
  var route = context[endpoint];
  app.use(endpoint,
    function(req,res,next){
      req.token= route.token;
      next();
    },
    require('./route-mixin'));
}
```

The problem that i am facing is that route-mixin method always gets the last token.`context` in this case is just the js file i added above. How can i pass different tokens for each route individually.

Comment: How does your route-mixin file look like?

Comment: function(req,res,nxt){console.log(req.token);res.send("test");}

Comment: @MichaelTroger i already tested without the middleware and it works all fine. but console.log is always showing the last token

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think with require you include the same instance of this object several times. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887318/understanding-node-js-modules-multiple-requires-return-the-same-object
So I would try to inline this function code

Comment: @MichaelTroger pretty sure that is not it because i even tried console.log in middleware in same file and that even gave the same response

Comment: That's the only thing which came to my mind:
app.use(endpoint,
    function(req,res,next){
      req.token= route.token;
      next();
    },
   function(req,res,nxt){
      console.log(req.token);
      res.send("test"‌​);
   }
);

I have no other idea, sry!

Comment: I got it working! I'll put it as an answer in the next minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to put the content within the loop into a closure.

What gave me the idea what's the issue in the first place, was the PhpStorm IDE:
[image: mutable variable is accessible from closure]

The error message `mutable variable is accessible from closure` appeared within the first middleware. This article [Mutable variable is accessible from closure. How can I fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724620/mutable-variable-is-accessible-from-closure-how-can-i-fix-this) gave me then the hint to use a closure.

So all what was necessary to get it running was changing:

```
   for(var endpoint in context){
         var route = context[endpoint];
         app.use(endpoint,
             function (req, res, next) {
                 req.token = route.token;
                 next();
             },
             function (req, res) {
                 console.log(req.token);
                 res.send('test');
             }
         );
    }
```

to:

```
for(var endpoint in context){
    (function() {
        var route = context[endpoint];
        app.use(endpoint,
            function (req, res, next) {
                req.token = route.token;
                next();
            },
            function (req, res) {
                console.log(req.token);
                res.send('test');
            }
        );
    })();
}
```

The full example code I was successfully running:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var context =  {
    "/home":{
        "token":"ksdjfglkas"
    },
    "/logout":{
        "token":"ksdjfglksaudhf"
    }
};
for(var endpoint in context){
    (function() {
        var route = context[endpoint];
        app.use(endpoint,
            function (req, res, next) {
                req.token = route.token;
                next();
            },
            function (req, res) {
                console.log(req.token);
                res.send('test');
            }
        );
    })();
}

app.listen(3000);
```