# Mutable variable is accessible from closure

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, variables

I have the following code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var file = data[i];
        $.getJSON("/types/" + file, function(json) {
            if (json[0] !== undefined) {
                console.log(json[0] + file);
            }
        });
    }
```

But my editor is saying "Mutable variable is accessible from closure". I've tried to change `function(json) {` to `function(json, file) {`, but this don't work because this is a default function of jquery.

I hope you can help my fixing the problem.

Comment: You've answered Mutable variable is accessible from closure. So, did you try using closure???

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13813463/435605

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For such loops, you need to put the contents in a closure.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    (function(){
        var file = data[i];
        $.getJSON("/types/" + file, function(json) {
            if (json[0] !== undefined) {
                console.log(json[0] + file);
            }
        });
    })();
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you need further explanation, just tell me ;)

Comment: Oh, du sprichst sogar Deutsch :)

Comment: @VanCoding: Can you explain your answer? From what I think, this would stop the value of 'i' from getting changed by other functions. is it ?

Answer (score 9):

You can use a closure as suggested, also it doesn't make your code easier to read, especially if your closure is inside a loop! Much easier and cleaner to simply create a function and call it on each iteration.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    doJson(data[i]);
}

function doJson(file) {
    $.getJSON("/types/" + file, function(json) {
        if (json[0] !== undefined) {
            console.log(json[0] + file);
        }
    });
}
```

Or you could simply update your loop to use `forEach` instead, because a new function get fired on each iteration the scope will be limited to it.

```
data.forEach(function(file) {

    $.getJSON("/types/" + file, function(json) {
        if (json[0] !== undefined) {
            console.log(json[0] + file);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: These options are much more clear and readable than the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

If you can use ES6, you could simply replace `var` with `let` and everything works as expected because `let` creates a new scope in every iteration of the for loop.

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var file = data[i];
        $.getJSON("/types/" + file, function(json) {
            if (json[0] !== undefined) {
                console.log(json[0] + file);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use closure : ( be careful when running functions in a loop).

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
    var file = data[i];

    (function(f)
    {

        $.getJSON("/types/" + f, function(json)
        {
            if (json[0] !== undefined)
            {
                console.log(json[0] + f);
            }
        })
    })(file);


}
```