# Does JavaScript create a new execution context when executing a block?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, v8, ecmascript-5

Does JavaScript create a new execution context when executing a block to associate the its lexical environment with it.

Comment: Check section "13.2.14Runtime Semantics: BlockDeclarationInstantiation" in https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-blockdeclarationinstantiation

Comment: Are you referencing a block outside of a function call or a block within a function call?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No**. An [execution context is essentially a call stack frame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35760441/1048572), while the lexical environment is the current scope. No function gets called when a block is evaluated.

You can read in the specification for the [evaluation semantics of blocks](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-block-runtime-semantics-evaluation) that it creates a new lexical environment (initialised with the variables in the block scope) that has the old environment as its parent, and "*Set[s] the running execution context’s `LexicalEnvironment` to [that value]*". After executing the statements in the block, the child environment is popped off again, but the running execution context did stay the same all the time.

Comment: After the execution of the block is finished, LexicalEnvironment will be set again to the lexical environment of the function block right ?

Comment: It will be set back to the lexical environment that was the execution context's lexical environment before entering the block statement. That's not necessarily the one of the `function`, it's whatever scope the block is found in.

Comment: Really useful answer. Thank you

Comment: even in the dev tools, you can see with block scope there is NO new callstack that gets created

Comment: Awesome answer @Bergi + 1. I have a somewhat related question. Only code between braces of if, for, while, etc is considered block, i.e. a function (code between braces of a function) is NOT considered block, right?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, the braces around function bodies don't form a block. The function body still gets its own scope though.

Comment: Great, thanks @Bergi, and when `any` function is called, a new execution context is started-created, right?

Comment: @Daniel Exactly