# Are execution context and closure the same thing in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have read several tutorials about closures. Some tutorials have some information about execution context. I am confused that execution context and closure seem to the same thing.Does anyone can explain this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Closures are functions which remember the environment they were created in.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Closures keep the reference to the lexical context where they are created. Check this to know more about lexical context: [Lexical environment and function scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599965/lexical-environment-and-function-scope). 
When the closures(functions) are executed, they are executed in execution context. 
So,

Closures => function, 
Execution context => environment

Comment: I am confused by Lexical context ,  Execution context  and Closures

Comment: @ChenLee I have edited the answer a bit. The detailed definition  of those concepts can be found all over the internet. The definitions are not clear always and it is easy to get confused between scope, lexical context, execution context etc. Only thing you can do is find more and learn more and that is how you become a world class developer.