# Lexical environment example explanation

Tags: javascript

I am following a JS tutorial and have come across this example below, and the first one makes sense from what I have learned so far:

```
function makeCounter() {
  function counter() {
    return counter.count++;
  };
  counter.count = 0;

  return counter;
}

let counter = makeCounter();
let counter1 = makeCounter();
console.log(counter());  // 0
console.log(counter());  // 1
console.log(counter1()); // 0
```

So, that makes sense since the new lexical environments are created each time we assign the `makeCounter` function to a new variable. What I don't understand is if I am using the property of the function `makeCounter` I am still incrementing the `makeCounter.count` if I assign it to new variables:

```
function makeCounter() {
  function counter() {
    return makeCounter.count++;
  };
  makeCounter.count = 0;

  return counter;
}

let counter = makeCounter();
let counter1 = makeCounter();
console.log(counter());  // 0
console.log(counter());  // 1
console.log(counter1()); // 2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lexical environment and function scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599965/lexical-environment-and-function-scope)

Comment: How is this a duplicate?

Comment: @AjayGaur This is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: in javascript, the syntax `makeCounter.count = 0;` (with the name of the function, not on an instance) is equivalent to a static property, compared to `this.count = 0;` which is non static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using a property of the function object is quite confusing here, especially if you want to learn about lexical environments. A better example might be the difference between

```
function makeCounter() {
  var count = 0;
  function counter() {
    return count++;
  }
  return counter;
}
```

and

```
var count = 0;
function makeCounter() {
  function counter() {
    return count++;
  }
  return counter;
}
```

where it is more obvious how many `count` variables there are, when they are created, and in which scope they live. Of course it works the same with the indirection through the `counter` vs `makeCounter` variables (that get initialised with function objects), which live in the same scopes as `count` does in my examples.

Admittedly, `makeCounter.count = 0` should better be outside of `makeCounter`, as otherwise the behaviour of resetting the global count will get *really* confusing. The exact property-less code corresponding to yours would be

```
function makeCounter() {
  var count;
  function counter() {
    return count++;
  }
  count = 0;
  return counter;
}
```

vs

```
var count;
function makeCounter() {
  function counter() {
    return count++;
  }
  count = 0;
  return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function counter and counter.count are defined new in the function scope of makeCounter in each call. 
makeCounter.count is defined once only for the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

> What I don't understand is if I am using the property of the function
>   `makeCounter` I am still incrementing the `makeCounter.count` if I assign
>   it to new variables:

`makeCounter` is **available in the scope in which it is defined** and **inside `makeCounter` definition** as well.

So, since `makeCounter.count` is not scoped exclusively local to `makeCounter` function definition, so both `counter` and `counter1` has access to the same reference of `makeCounter.count`.

Answer (score 0):

New lexical scope is created every time and when makeCounter() returns it remembers count value in clojure. In simple words, it's a language feature that allows functions to remember variables from scope where a function was defined.

It allows to make 'private' like variables in Javascript.